# input selects into variables

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a form with looped checkbox inputs inside of it. I am trying to find a way to find all the checked inputs inside of the form, and store the values of all the checked inputs as an array, and put that array inside of a variable that can be passed into the function qryPrjctAdmin(). So basically `onchange='qryPrjctAdmin(`'all the checked inputs' values as an array inside a variable here'`)'`. I'm pretty stumped on this one. Here's my code:

```
  echo "<form onchange='qryPrjctAdmin()'>";
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='userMeeting[]' value=". $row['Id'] .">" . $row['fullName'] . "</input>";
         }
  echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your HTML is not valid. `<input />` elements cannot have a closing tag. They are self closing. Then, you could do what you want like this:

```js
function qryPrjctAdmin() {
  var checkedInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name="userMeeting[]"]:checked');
  // Convert this HTMLCollection into an Array and map their values
  var values = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkedInputs)
                    .map(function(checkbox) { return checkbox.value; });
  console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<form onchange='qryPrjctAdmin()'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='userMeeting[]' value="a" />A</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='userMeeting[]' value="b" />B</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='userMeeting[]' value="c" />C</label>
</form>
```